# How to see the contents of boot partition

Tags: boot

Does anybody know how to mount the boot partition?On my nexus 7, I booted to recovery and tried to mount the boot partition using the following-

mount -t ext4 /dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/boot /boot

But this failed.
I tried to do read-only mount and mount using vfat, but with no success.

Answer (score 2):

The boot.img file is a `bootfs` partition. I also tried to mount this partition, but in the end I stumbled upon [this](http://www.enck.org/tools.html#split_bootimg) script. It may help you solve your problem.